# How to continue with the script even if I have errors in the selenium ide chrome extension?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have a script that stops sometimes due to errors but I want this not to happen and I want it to continue and ignore the errors.
I don't know how to do this, I have the following code that I have made, how can I do it?
thanks

What the script does is to open a web page, fill in fields and accept them. When it reaches the end it checks that there is not a specific word and if there is it emits a sound.

I attach the code

[image: 1]

I have tried store | true | !errorignore
Did not work
After executing and putting it with conditionals it doesn't work, any idea how to do it?